Increment a relative row reference by more than 1 row when copying a formula down to the next row
I have a worksheet in Excel 2010 where I have Win/Loss results represented by 1/0 in cqolumn AC starting in AC46 and then on every 21st row that follows.
I use the following formula to  return a "W" for 1, or "L" for 0, if the row has a value.
=IF(AC46="","",
   IF(AC46=1,"W",
     IF(AC46=0,"L","")))

If I copy the formula down to the next row, all the references to AC46 become AC47, but my next Win/Loss result is in AC67.
Is it possible to drag a formula down a row but have a the cell reference increment by more than 1 row?
I want to copy it down the column but have  the row references increment by 21 rows instead of 1.
For example, I want the next row's formula to be:
=IF(AC67="","", 
   IF(AC67=1,"W",
     IF(AC67=0,"L","")))

and the one after:
=IF(AC88="","", 
   IF(AC88=1,"W",
     IF(AC88=0,"L","")))

and so on.

If you define two cells then select both cells and drag the formula to the next cell Excel should continue the pattern. Without some sample data that’s all I am willing to share.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you could use INDIRECT and ROW to help with that.  Having said that, adding more context (by editing your post) may result in alternative suggestions for you to consider.

I have written an answer that corresponds to your question, now please rewrite your Q so that it is clear whether my guessing is correct or not.


Type what is below in A2,
=OFFSET($A$10,ROWS($A$2:A2)*$B$2,0,1,1)
and the number 1 in B2
Then in A11 also the number 1,
A12: =A11+1,
fill A12 down any number of cell you wish
Fill A2 down till A10.

Change the number in B2 to see A2 to A10 change values.
Succesful test in LibreOffice

B2 determines
which of the values in A11 and downward
to show in A2 to A10.

Replace A46 in your first formula with the formula in step 1 (remove = obviously)
Either replace $B$2 with 67 directly,
or place 67 in any cell and replace $B$2 with a fixed reference
(absolute, with $ as shown for B2)  to that cell.


Try this formula:
Enter the formula in A1:
=IF(AC1="","",IF(AC1=1,"W",IF(AC1=0,"L","")))

Then enter the formula in A2:
=IF(INDIRECT("AC"&ROW(A1)+20)="","",IF(INDIRECT("AC"&ROW(A1)+20)=1,"W",IF(INDIRECT("AC"&ROW(A1)+20)=0,"L","")))

Then you can drag the formula in A2.


Note to the use of INDIRECT; the sheet (or workbook?) will always be "volatile" - so will recalculate more often (or in higher grade), and "always" be seen as "not saved" as you're closing it.

Excel 2010
=IF(OFFSET(AC$46, 21*(ROW(AC46)-ROW(AC$46)),)=1, "W", 
   IF(OFFSET(AC$46, 21*(ROW(AC46)-ROW(AC$46)),)&""="0", "L",
     "")) 


Formula uses 21*n as the OFFSET function's row argument where
n is the difference between the number of the first row containming the formula, AC$46 in the example, and the current row containing the formula. In this way for every additional row, the row offset increases by 21.
To test for the presence of 0, the cell value is converted to a string. In this way, it doesn't also need to be tested for an empty value thus reducing the length of the formula. This works because an empty value is equivalent to 0, but an empty string is not equivalent to the string "0":
true  = AND(ISBLANK(x), x=0)
false = AND(ISBLANK(x), ""&x="0")
true  = 1-1 &"" = "0"  



Excel 365
You specified Excel 2010 however should you use Excel 365 in the future, the formula can be adapted using LET to reduce the length as follows:
=LET(
   val,OFFSET(AC$46, 21*(ROW(AC46)-ROW(AC$46)),),
   IF(val=1, "W", IF(val&""="0", "L", "")))


Yes this actually worked and does what I was asking brilliant thank you so much you are a genius 1. for understanding my rather vague question and 2. for solving it.

If you feel that this answer or any other is helpful, you can optionally vote on it or accept it.  See "What can I do when someone answers my question?"
